# Programatically remove wifi (Wireless Network Connection) icon from system tray (notification area) in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, system-tray, notification-area

I want to remove wifi notification icon from system tray using C#. How this can be achieved?

**Modified**:

I do not want to disable wifi or any other network connection but hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the Network system notification icon. The following registry commands should do that for you. You can run the command via a command line like `regedit regcmd.reg` or simply add the keys manually using C#. For more info see this [article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19085-system-icons-enable-disable.html).

- [Disable the Network Icon](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/140689d1298779770-system-icons-enable-disable-disable_network_notification_icon.reg)
- [Enable the Network Icon](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/140688d1298779770-system-icons-enable-disable-enable_network_notification_icon.reg)

Comment: I will try & let know. Thanks Geotarget

Comment: I tried that both via programatically (Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s Disable_Network_Notification_Icon.reg");
            regeditProcess.WaitForExit();) & double click reg file & restarting the machine (Tested in XP). Nothing happened. I still can access wifi & change it on system tray. Is it because of XP?

Comment: This is for Windows 7. XP has different commands. Search google for more info.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for my requirements in windows 7. Thanks Geotarget.